# Inverting Capitalization of letter in C

Tags: c, function

ok so i was asked to invert capitalization in C using a function inver_caps. My function works and prints the new letter correctly, but im having trouble as to why in the main it will not print correctly?

Any ideas?

```
void invert_caps (char letter);
int main(void){

    char lettermain;

    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &lettermain);

    invert_caps(lettermain);

    printf("The invert of the letter is %c \n", lettermain);

system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}

void invert_caps (char letter){

    printf("\nletter is %d\n",letter); /*this was used for debugging*/

    if ((int)letter >=65 && (int)letter<=90){

        letter = (int)letter+32;
    }else{

        letter = (int)letter - 32;
    }

    printf("\nnew letter is %d or %c\n",letter, letter); /*this was used for debugging*/
return letter;

}
```

Comment: You are doing pass by value, do pass by pointer, Or simply return converted value from function

Comment: read up on 'pass by value' and 'pass by pointer' and 'pass by reference'.

Comment: ^^ Or, return `letter`. Honestly - you really should consider starting with a beginner's book on C.

Comment: also your program is not portable. use `toupper`, `tolower`, `isupper` and `islower`. 65, 90, 32 etc are not guaranteed by the C Standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic reason you are not getting the inversion in the main method is you are only passing a copy of `lettermain` to `invert_caps()` method. 
Rather than that do the following,

```
void invert_caps (char letter);
int main(void){

    char lettermain;

    printf("\n=========Question 8=========\n");
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &lettermain);

    lettermain=invert_caps(lettermain);

    printf("The invert of the letter is %c \n", lettermain);

system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}

char invert_caps (char letter){

    printf("\nletter is %d\n",letter);

    if ((int)letter >=65 && (int)letter<=90){

        letter = (int)letter+32;
    }else{

        letter = (int)letter - 32;
    }

    printf("\nnew letter is %d or %c\n",letter, letter); /*this was used for debugging*/
return letter; 

}
```

Comment: If that works for you can you accept the answer? Because it's good for future SO users. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more help.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing pass by value (copy value), that doesn't reflects change made in calling at caller function. Do

(1) pass by pointer (pass address), Or
(2) simply return converted value from function.

Side note: Don't use ascii values in code, just use char constants to keep code readable (you don't have to remember ascii value). 
For example I write (2) solution for you (I believe that will be easy for you presently, avoiding pointer at this stage).

to understand the code read comments:

```
 char invert_caps (char letter){
// ^ added return type, its not void now 
    if ( letter >= 'A' && letter<= 'Z'){ // not using ASCII value but char Constants  
        letter = letter + ('a' - 'A');              // its more readable 
                       // Note 32 = 'a' - 'A' that is 97 - 54 
    }
    else { 
      if ( letter >= 'a' && letter<= 'z'){// Add this case, to be safe is good practice 
          letter = letter - ('a' - 'A');
      }
      else 
          letter = '\0'; // if letter is neither Upper or lower alphabetic case   
    }                    // then convened it into nul symbol (exception case)  
    return letter;  // added a line 
}
// I removed unnecessary typecasts and debug statements
```

In main() you need to call it like at same place:

```
lettermain = invert_caps(lettermain);
//  ^ return value assigned to variable `lettermain`
```

[return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sta56yeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a key word in C. The [return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sta56yeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement terminates the execution of a function and returns control to the calling function. A return statement can also return a value to the calling function and from function `invert_caps()` we are returning converted value.

Comment: Notice: I made a mistake written `X` instead of `Z`, but immediately I could find bug because I am using char constant **not** ascii values that you can't memorize.

Comment: I was talking about `32`. It's as bad as using the raw ascii value

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry didn't get you? are you saying char constants are int types in C

Comment: `letter = letter + 32;`

Comment: You didn't test this code did you? Hint: it always returns an upper-case letter.

Comment: It looks correct now. I added an answer that uses library functions and abuses the ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small routine using library functions to detect and change letter case.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int invert_case(int c)
{
    return islower(c) ? toupper(c) : isupper(c) ? tolower(c) : c;
}
```

If you don't like the nested `?:` ternary operators, here is the same logic using `if`.

```
int invert_case(int c)
{
    if (islower(c)) {
        return toupper(c);
    }
    if (isupper(c)) {
        return tolower(c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Note: this can be made even simpler, see *Dave's* comment below.

Comment: instead of `C` i will like return `'\0'`, but `c` is even correct (unchanged ) but its nice!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: This code will leave numbers, punctuation, and control characters unchanged.

Comment: Why didn't you use `isalpha()`? Even if `isalpha()` is equivalent to `(islower(c) || isupper(c))` just for this particular scenario. `isalpha()` would have been semantically more correct.

Comment: @Kira: I've added a version of the same logic using `if` instead of the nested `?:` ternary operators. I only call `toupper()` on lower-case letters and `tolower()` on upper-case letters. Any non-alpha characters are returned unchanged. `isalpha()` isn't really needed here.

Comment: if the input isn't uppercase or lowercase, then `toupper` and `tolower` will leave it unchanged. In other words, you only need one `if` in this function.

Comment: @Dave: I just checked a language reference and you are right. I'm too lazy to change it now.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you pass the `lettermain` variable from `main`, it's *copied*.

You need to either return the new character, or pass the variable by reference.

Comment: ok so i did     return letter; in the function, still doesnt work

Comment: @ace And you assign the returned letter to the `lettermain` variable?